# Any point to OAuth for in-house app?

Tags: oauth

The more I dig into OAuth the more I realize it's about authorization for third-party consumers. A few weeks ago [I asked about an allowance for in-house apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24332662/oauth-exceptions-for-primary-website-app) whereby they don't need to redirect customers, since practically speaking it doesn't make much sense to say something like 'The facebook app would like permission to access your information on facebook'...

Thinking this through further, why bother with OAuth at all for an in-house app?

Comment: Correct - if you can't trust yourself, who can you trust?

Comment: Thanks Andy, this question is kind of a sanity check for me and hopefully will save me some time for the release of our V1 app.